# Display error message if inquiry not in mySQL databases

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I have this code in a cgi text file:

```
if inquiry == "Number":
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from NUMBER_INFO where NUMBER_ID = "%s";' %(inquiry))
    number_info = cursor.fetchall()
    number = number_info[0][1]
```

In essence a user inputs a value and it searches through my mysql database and outputs a value.

I was wondering how do I print an error message, such as the value is not in database, if whatever the user inputs is not found in the database?

All I know is that the mysql database returns empty set.

Answer (score 0):

isn't it just

```
if not number_info:
    print "nothing's there"
else:
    number = number_info[0][1]
```

?